# No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'performStringGeocode'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been looking through all the questions that are of the form "no visible @interface for *class* declares the selector *method*" and none of them shed much light on what this error actually means. I'm a newb, so sorry if this is a silly mistake.

I'm looking for an explanation about what this error means, and maybe some corrections on how to get the error to go away in my code! hah!

The error is: No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'performStringGeocode'

```
//MapViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) NSString *fromAddr;
@end
```

.

```
//MapViewController.m
@interface MapViewController ()
@end
@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize fromAddr;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
if (self.isAddrPresent)
    [self.fromAddr performStringGeocode]; //<-- Angry error on this line
}
- (void)performStringGeocode:(NSString*) addr{
//geocode stuff
}
```

Comment: It simply means that the interface (the .h file) for a class, in this case NSString, doesn't have a method called performStringGeocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because no visible interface of `NSString` declares the selector `performSTringGeocode`.

In fact, it is a method of `MapViewController`, as far as your code is telling.

Try

```
[self performStringGeocode:[self fromAddr]];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
[self.fromAddr performStringGeocode];
```

What you meant is:

```
[self performStringGeocode:self.fromAddr];
```

As for the error, it means `self.fromAddr` appears to be an `NSString` object, and there does not appear to be any `performStringFromGeocode` method on the `NSString` class.